# Dynamic AMP Email Template

Tags: amp-email

I want to send emails which *will contain list of items* and based on the list the receiver can fill a form and submit.
I will be doing the form submission part using AMP, But can I register the AMP template using one item and the list will change as dynamically from email to email. Or do I have to fetch the list using amp-list as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by "register the AMP template using one item".

You can either embed the list directly in the email payload (i.e., static for the lifetime of the email, though different emails can embed different lists) or use amp-list to render the list (i.e., dynamic for the lifetime of the email). It's up to you.

Comment: To send AMP mails we need to register the template so asking if I register with one item and then start sending multiple items in future, that too with updated list item details. Will it work?

Comment: You mean the registration with the email clients (Gmail, Yahoo! Mail)? That's a one-time process. As long as you pass the registration the first time, subsequent changes to the email from the same sender email address don't require re-approval.

Comment: cool thats what I was worried about
Thanks